# Vue.js: <datepicker> does not display inside a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am converting a mini-form that includes vue-strap datepicker component besides other standard HTML elements and a button into a component. When I use that component, everything displays correctly, except the datepicker, which is not displayed at all. This is the component code.

```
   Vue.component('create-activity', {
     props: ['item',
          'intouchTypes',
          'index',
          'date_format',
          'date_placeholder',
          'actionSuccess',
          'actionMessage',
        ],
   template: `<div>
    <div class="two-column" style="float:right;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #cccccc; padding:10px;">                
    <div class="fieldrow">
    <div class="fieldlabel">In-Touch Date:</div>
            <div class="fieldinput">
                <datepicker v-model="item.intouch_date" 
                            :format="date_format"
                            :clear-button="true"
                            :placeholder="date_placeholder" 
                        >
                </datepicker>
   ....
   ....
```

The vue-strap datepicker seems to be registering, as if I don't include define a property (e.g. date_format) that is used by datepicker, Vue displays an error: ReferenceError: date_format is not defined.

I am using the create-activity component like this

```
<create-activity v-bind:item="item" 
        v-bind:intouch-types="intouchTypes" 
        v-bind:date_format="date_format"
        v-bind:date_placeholder="date_placeholder"
        v-bind:action-success="actionSuccess"
        v-bind:action-message="actionMessage"
    ></create-activity>
```

Is there any reason that datepicker should not display in my component?

NOTE: Just to clarify, all other HTML elements display and work correctly for the 'create-activity' component, except that datepicker is not displayed at all.

Comment: Can you share the code for how you use your `create-activity` component? Are you sure the `date_format` prop is being passed in correctly, and it has a valid value?

Comment: I have edited my post to show the use of create-activity component, Yes, date_format has a valid value. When I use {{date_format}}, it displays 'dd MMM yyyy'

Comment: Great, thanks! And what library is `datepicker` coming from? That is not a standard HTML element.

Comment: datepicker uses the vue-strap.min.js library. I would like to add that when I use datepicker code directly (i.e. not through component), it displays the datepicker.

Comment: don't you need backticks around your template string ?

Comment: Yes, I have backticks around the template string; sorry, it was not show in the sample code. I have updated the sample code to show backticks.